# installing and running Gadget 2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: c, makefile

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question and I will just post anyway.

I am just starting to learn SPH simulation. I was following this tutorial: https://astrobites.org/2011/04/02/installing-and-running-gadget-2/

It seems I succesfully generated the executable Gadget2 inside the /Gadget2 directory, then I copied both the Gadget2 executable and galaxy.param file to a newly created galaxy directory. However when I run:

```
mpirun -np 2 ./Gadget2 ./galaxy.param
```

I get the following error:

```
./Gadget2: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./Gadget2: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I believe it has to do something with my Makefile. I am sharing the adjust settings for target computer part, if it gives any hint to the error:

```
#--------------------------------------- Select target computer

SYSTYPE="trina"
#SYSTYPE="Mako"
#SYSTYPE="Regatta"
#SYSTYPE="RZG_LinuxCluster"
#SYSTYPE="RZG_LinuxCluster-gcc"
#SYSTYPE="OpteronMPA"
#SYSTYPE="OPA-Cluster32"
#SYSTYPE="OPA-Cluster64"


#--------------------------------------- Adjust settings for target computer

ifeq ($(SYSTYPE),"trina")
CC       =  mpicc  
OPTIMIZE =  -O3 -Wall
GSL_INCL = -I/usr/local/include
GSL_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib
FFTW_INCL= -I/usr/local/include
FFTW_LIBS= -L/usr/local/lib
MPICHLIB = -L/usr/lib
endif
```

I thought if there were error in makefile, the executable would not have created at the first place. But the executable was there and I have this error. I would very much appreciate if anyone has any suggestion on this. thanks

Comment: Did you compile or/and install libgsl?

Comment: yes I did , and I just rebooted my system and the simulation starting to run. I now have few output files . thanks